# BGProcessingTask not fired when device not connected to external power

Tags: ios, scheduled-tasks

I'm able to schedule and run a BGProcessingTask and it works fine, but only if the device is connected to the external power. I've tried to set requiresExternalPower = false but nothing changes. To be sure my task send an email when it starts so I can monitor it. When I disconnect the power cable the task is not lunched anymore. Is there any solution?